# How to make links in a textview not clickable except the chosen one

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, textview

I have a textview like following (Just an example the text is dynamic)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/msgtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="hi visit: www.abc.com  or http://www.cde.com or efg.com or www.mywebsite.com or mywebsite.com/privacy.php"
        />
```

How is it possible to make links from mywebsite.com only clickable.

Means In the above textview www.mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com/privacy.php only be the clickable links.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like below.

```
view.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href="Your URL">This is a link</a>"));
```

Comment: Well, actually the text is dynamic so i can't accept your question. The text in question is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do `setText(stuff)`

Parse it to find out the indicies `start`/`end` of where your url is.

Then you will need to use `SpannableString` and `ClickableSpan`

Followed by something like this:

`span.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

Now go ahead `setText` and `setMovementMethod`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgtext);

 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("hi visit:" +
                "<a href=\"http:/www.abc.com">www.abc.com</a> "+"the rest of your text"));
 textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```